# Wordpress homepage posts "view more" button linking to 4-revision-v1?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've recently been asked to relocate and modify a WordPress site which uses a custom template and some custom plugins. I'm fairly new to WordPress and PHP so feel free to let me know if I'm using incorrect terminology etc. here..
The way things are set up on this site/template seem rather irregular but I'm unsure if it's normal for WordPress lol.

The homepage contains some static content plus a list of recent posts (which are actually woocommerce products). Beneath the list of recent posts/products there is a "view more" button.

You can see the site [here](http://mooreriveraccommodation.com).

On the original server and my test environment, this button is linking as expected to the page "../holiday-homes" displaying the full list of products, however on the new server it is linking to "../4-revision-v1".

I've tried:

- setting the permalinks to default and back again (they're set to "post name" and "product")
- Reuploading the theme file
- disabling plugins (which basically breaks the site completely as most of the pages rely on one or another)
- checked that the Static front page "posts page" dropdown contains the correct page

I'm unsure what file generates this link and I cannot figure out what I need to change to fix it. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Tried so far...

- Tried adding "$post = get_post( /*$post_ID*/ ); _wp_upgrade_revisions_of_post( $post, wp_get_post_revisions( $post_ID ) );" to functions.php file
- ran search/replace script to ensure URLs are changed from old to new
- setting post status to draft and back to publish

Would like to look at the code that generates the link but not sure where to look :/

Problem appears to be corrected by manually changing "4-revision-v1" and "34-revision-v1" to "holiday-homes" in the database... Hope it sticks.

Now I'm on to [my last remaining problem with this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625367/wordpress-custom-single-product-php-correct-img-src-wrong-srcset) (I hope)

Comment: Can you go to edit that 'holiday-homes' page in the WordPress admin area and check what the slug is?

Comment: @JamesJones It is 'holiday-homes'. However the edit view doesn't display the same content as the actual holiday-homes page. There is  page-template in the theme which appears to control this (holiday_home.php)

Comment: Roger that. Can you try using a default WordPress theme? If it then works you narrow it down to the theme. If no luck there, when you relocated the site did the URL change?

Comment: This seems similar to your problem. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-url-changing-to-include-revision-v1-when-ediitng-page. Try adding this to your theme `functions.php` file

Comment: `$post = get_post(  /*$post_ID*/  ); _wp_upgrade_revisions_of_post( $post, wp_get_post_revisions( $post_ID ) );`

Comment: Also try changing the status of your post and back again. What status is it at right now?

Comment: Tried changing the status, (it's published), no change. Added that to functions.php, no change (does it matter where in the file it goes?) When I try a default theme I don't have the button to click at all lol.

Comment: shows the guestbook posts on default template, instead of holiday home posts
And yes the site url has changed

Comment: WordPress can be pretty finicky when you change url. If you just did find replace on the db this will not work as parameters are stored in serialised arrays. Use this script to change the url https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/. You also cannot just change url in the admin screens and expect everything to work fine sadly. Hopefully you still have the original  db.

Comment: @JamesJones for some reason the link has now changed to "/under-construction/4-revision-v1/"... Also, I notice in the editor, in the holiday-home page attributes, it does not have a "template" option, which is does have on my working local version. Could this be significant?

Comment: I didn't do any search and replace in the database, i wasn't aware that this was necessary... I will give that a try

Comment: When I navigate to the folder containing the script, I get page not found O_o

Comment: have you placed the script in the root web folder? I should mention when you're done with the script to delete it as it's a huge security risk.

Comment: Ok, have run the script... checking to see if anything has improved..

Comment: Still linking to "../under-construction/4-revision-v1/" :(

Comment: Bugger. Did you run the script on the original database? What did you use as find/replace values?

Comment: If you did it all right and it didn't fix, the next thing you need is update your question with the code that generates that link in the theme

Comment: I backed up the database then ran it on the live DB, find: original url replace: new url. Is there anything else I would need to replace? I just did a dry run on searching for 4-revision-v1 replace with holiday-home and it found 4 cases..2 are "4-revision-v1" and 2 are "34-revision-v1". Should I do a live run or is there a way to not change the "34-revision-v1" in case it doesn't need changing?

Comment: if I migrate site from http://www.oldurl.com to http://www.newurl.com I'd  search for 'www.oldurl.com' and replace with 'www.newurl.com' using the script. The 'revision' url is most likely something wordpress is generating programmatically, so not something you want to search replace.

Comment: Problem is I don't know where the code is that generated that link in the theme lol! The settings for the front page (in customise) are Static front page displays Front page --Select-- (as in not set), Posts Page: Holiday Homes. Where should I look for the code that makes the holiday homes Post list on the side? In the meantime I'll update the post to show what has been done so far.. Thanks

Comment: You can't look in the WordPress admin screens. You have to look at the actual php files. I'd start with the template in the theme that generates that page.

Comment: Just for curiosities sake, I changed the rows containing 4-revision-v1 in the DB manually, and it now appears to be working as expected!

Comment: Well bloody hell. Nice work. You should add your solution as an answer to your own question. Might help someone else someday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JamesJones for helping me troubleshoot this problem and pointing me to [This script: ../interconnectit.com/products/](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) which didn't fix my issue directly but helped me locate a couple of places in the database that required a change.

Problem appears to have be corrected by manually changing "4-revision-v1" and "34-revision-v1" to "holiday-homes" in the database. Sometimes the simplest solution is best eh lol!

No idea how the problem came about in the first place, but maybe this will help someone else sometime :)